# Ansible Playbook always interactively asks for Become password, even though no become user is specified?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook that copies a script and executes a script on an EC2 instance.

```
- name: Playbook Deploy jar
  hosts: all
  remote_user: ubuntu
  tasks:
    - name: Copy Provisioning Script
      copy:
        src: ./prod-setup.sh
        dest: .
        mode: '0755'

    - name: Execute the Provisioning script
      command: sh ./prod-setup.sh
```

The .pem file used to connect to the host is specified in the 'Hosts' file. There is no become user but everytime I run it, I am interactively queried for a become password.

```
$superuser: ansible-playbook -i hosts -K playbook.yml
BECOME Password:
```

No Become password is set because there is no become user so literally pressing 'Enter' is sufficient to continue execution but this means I can't deploy this playbook as part of a script.

I checked ansible.cfg and none of the settings have been overridden. There are no other config files. What else could be causing this? Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly asking to be prompted for the privilege escalation password by running `-K` which according to the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html) is:

> -K, --ask-become-pass
> ask for privilege escalation password

Try running the `ansible-playbook` command without the `-K`

Comment: wow I guess I need to read my docs better. I had assumed K was the flag for passing in a .yml file